# how to insert decimal data type into sql server from php

Tags: php, sql-server

This error annoyed me

> [SQLSTATE] => 42000
>
> [code] => 8114
>
> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

when i remove `' '` this it display

> [SQLSTATE] => 42000
>
> [code] => 102
>
> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.

I try to insert amount data from web page(PHP), but I don't know if I can use `CAST` or `CONVERT`

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST' && isset($_POST['save'])) 
    {
        $save = "INSERT INTO trans_details 
        (badge_id,user_id,comp_id,amount,cash,subsidy,trans_date) 
        values('$badge_id','$user_id','$cid','$amount','$total_need','$amount',$stamp)"; 
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $save);
    }
```

meanwhile, At the my database `amount` and `total_need` are declared as `decimal(12,2)`. And I tried to use `isNumeric()` function but it store value 1? What can I do to store directly from php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another good reason to use prepared statements. Try this out:

```
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
    $query      = "INSERT INTO trans_details (
                       badge_id, user_id, comp_id, amount, cash, subsidy, trans_date
                   )
                   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $parameters = [$badge_id, $user_id, $cid, $amount, $total_need, $amount, $stamp]; 
    $result     = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parameters);
}
```

This will avoid any problems with quoting, and make your queries safer.

Answer (score 0):

For insert numeric value don't add `''` over value

```
$save = "INSERT INTO trans_details 
        (badge_id,user_id,comp_id,amount,cash,subsidy,trans_date) 
        values('$badge_id','$user_id','$cid',$amount,$total_need,'$amount',$stamp)"; 
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $save);
```

Comment: display this error _Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. ) )_

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of localization/regional settings, you probably have configured PHP with a locale that uses a comma (`,`) for the decimal point separator instead of a dot (`.`) , for example supposing that $product_id is `1` and `$price` is `1.23` when you do:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO products (product_id, price) values ($product_id,$price)";
```

your are getting:

```
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1,1,23) -- three values: 1, 1 and 23
```

instead of:

```
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1,1.23) -- two values: 1 and 1.23
```

Possible solutions:

- Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) instead of creating the query string manually. This also helps protect you from [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).
- If for any reason you can't use prepared statements use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for converting the values to string, that function has an optional parameter for specifying the decimal point character (also set the thousands separator as `''`).
- Change the locale of PHP with [`set_locale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), note that this will affect **all** conversions, so maybe is not an option for you if you need to output numbers formatted with your current locale.